# How to refresh table view such that index is updated too?

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, indexing, tableview

Currently, I am implementing a post system such that users can like posts but can only like them once, using firebase. After the post is liked, firebase updates the date, and the app reorders the posts based off the like date, as such

```
if changedPost.Revealed == "true" {

     changedPost.revealDate = value["revealedDate"] as? Double ?? 00000
     self.orderedPostList = self.postList.sorted(by: { $0.revealDate! > $1.revealDate! })
     if let newName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "information").value as? NSDictionary {

           changedPost.name = newName["posterName"] as? String ?? "Poster not found"
     }
     self.tableView.reloadData()       
 }
```

The liking mechanism is based off

```
 let location : CGPoint = sender.location(in: self.tableView)

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)?.row {

            let postIDLocation = postList[indexPath]
            let postIDPressed = postIDLocation.postID
            let numberOfRevealsPostNeeds = postIDLocation.revealsRequired
            let numberOfReveals = Int(postIDLocation.Reveals!)
            let revealReference = Database.database().reference().child("reveals").child(postIDPressed!)

            revealReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

                if snapshot.hasChild(userID!) {
                    print ("hello")
                }
                else {

                    revealReference.updateChildValues([userID!: "true"])
                    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postIDPressed!)
                    let addedReveal = numberOfReveals + 1
```

The problem is, after a user likes the post, it moves to the top of the feed, such that a new post will occupy the position the liked post had once occupied. However, the user is now unable to like the post that was there because that position on the table view used to be occupied by the post that is now liked. When the user restarts the app, they are able to like the post that occupies the position that had once held the post already liked. Is there a way to readjust the table view indexes after the posts are reordered? They are currently stored in a dictionary as such:

```
orderedPostList = postList.sorted(by: { $0.revealDate! > $1.revealDate! })
```

I have tried refreshing the table view, but the indexes are still associated with the wrong posts. Basically, the posts are fetched from firebase and then sorted into a dictionary based off their liked date; however, when the like date changes, the post position changes but the new post that occupies the liked post's previous position cannot be liked until the app is restarted and indexes refreshed.

Comment: It doesn't look like a good way of presenting code.

Comment: What do you mean @El Tomato ? Should I reorganize the question ? I thought that that was the only relevant code to the question.

Comment: You have three or more curly brackets missing.

Comment: @ElTomato I excluded those , only including the pertinent parts of the code. If I continue the code to the curly brackets, there's other things that occur. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the like mechanism was using the unordered dictionary. When I made the like mechanism's gesture recognizer use the index from the ordered dictionary, the like went to the correct post.